# how to get same date as one array

Tags: javascript

I have an array,

```
data =[{"date":"12/1/12","value":21},
       {"date":"12/2/12","value":34},
       {"date":"12/1/12","value":36},
       {"date":"12/1/12","value":32},
       {"date":"12/2/12","value":1},
       {"date":"12/2/12","value":4},
       {"date":"12/2/12","value":3},]
```

i need to create another array like by retrieving values from the arrays,

```
data1=[{"date":"12/1/12","value":21},
       {"date":"12/1/12","value":36},
       {"date":"12/1/12","value":32}]

data2 =[{"date":"12/2/12","value":3},
        {"date":"12/2/12","value":4},
        {"date":"12/2/12","value":1},
        {"date":"12/2/12","value":34}]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Since you did not post your attempt, try looking at [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of Array.

Comment: @YongQuan—I'd use [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), there are many options. ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const data1 = data.filter(datum => datum.date === ‘12/1/12’)
const data2 = data.filter(datum => datum.date === ‘12/2/12’)
```